# Why do the Angular docs recommend against ng-init in most cases?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From [the ng-init documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

That doc goes on to give the following example:

```
<div ng-repeat="innerList in list" ng-init="outerIndex = $index">
    // [snip]
</div>
```

What makes it appropriate to use `ng-init` with `ng-repeat` but not, for example, with `ng-model` like this:

```
<input ng-model="thing.prop"
       ng-init="thing.prop = thing.prop || 'defaultValue'">
```

The doc says one should "use controllers rather than ngInit". What benefit does a controller offer in this case? Is this an Angular stylistic preference, or are there cases in which code like the above will not work?

Comment: The basic idea is most model data initialized in controller or outside ng-init (scope) gives us more control in maintainability of the model.

Comment: Data should be initialized in the controller and not the view. In MVC the controller should populate the model.

Answer (score -1):

That's because the documentation should be as concise as posible, and if in each example they create a Controller, it won't be so precise and clear